# Why does Word 2016 remove Field Code switches in .odt?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, field-codes

When editing .odt files in Word 2016 using the { [REF] Bookmark [Switches ] } field code the document seems to work fine. For example referencing *1.2.3.4 Heading* with `{ REF _Ref1234 \w }` results in *1.2.3.4*.

When the document is closed and reopened the result becomes *Heading*. Looking at the field code after reopening it has become `{ REF _Ref1234 }`. Adding the switch only results in the correct output only until the document is closed and reponed, when the problem reoccurs.

What is the reason for this? Is there any way of using field codes with .odt in Word 2016?